# How to extend a custom NASolver in ArcGIS Server 10.1?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, c#, arcgis-10.1, network-analyst

The past year we developed a custom NASolver with C# , it works fine and that job has finished.

Now we are planning to use it from ArcGIS Server. The problem is that we have no information for that. The creation of a new Server Object Extensions could be a solution, but it will take time...

We want to know if exists another way to do that by extending the iNAServer object.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, SOE(Server Object Extension) can be used only for MapService. So, the best way is implement your custom NASolver as custom GP Tool and publish it to GP Service. Then you could run NASolver by GP Service. Please read the following site "Do you need an SOE?" section.
"What is a server object extension?"
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/na/0154000004s5000000/

And here is the help how to create custom GP tool.
"Custom geoprocessing function tools"
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000mrs000000

Hope this help you.